# MathematicalProgram: Group lumped parameters by defining new variables

Tags: drake

I have a version of the following problem:
I have a `MathematicalProgram` with decision variables `a`, `b`, `c` that only ever appear in lumped form, such as `ab`, `bc`. I now want to construct a new set of decision variables, defining `m1 := ab` and `m2 := bc` and solve the `MathematicalProgram` with respect to these new variables.

The idea is that the optimization should now be linear in the new set of parameters, and I really only care about their lumped values. However, I don't know how lumping occurs a priory and hence can only define the non-lumped parameters. In particular, I obtain the lumped parameters from [DecomposeLumpedParameters](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1symbolic.html#ae8c85e424b3109ed84a5bb309238bc3c).

How would I go about achieving this? Is there a way of doing this automatically with the `MathematicalProgram` API, or can I achieve this somehow by substituting the old parameters with the new ones in my expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a super clean answer to the most general version of this problem.

As you've written it, you have costs and/or constraints with an `Eval` method of the form

```
f(a,b,c) = ab + bc + ...
```

and you want to automatically convert this to

```
g(x=ab, y=bc) = x + y + ...
```

For costs/constraints that support `Eval<Expression>`, one could actually use `DecomposeLumpedParameters` again on the cost/constraint evaluator to extract those terms. But in general it is hard to go in this direction. (It's much easier to go from g(x,y) => f(a,b,c), but because you can do symbolic substitution of x=ab, y=bc, or nested function evaluation for cost/constraints that only support `Eval<AutoDiffXd>`.)

But, having talked to you about this briefly face2face, I think for your specific problem there is almost certainly a more narrow solution to your particular instance, which should work on the expressions before you get to the generality of MathematicalProgram.